# Error on compiling a Azure Function on Visual Studio Code in Node

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I'm trying to compile a Function on the Visual Code Studio but I'm getting the following error:

[image: Error output]

Function.js

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outputTable",
      "tableName": "contmaticTable",
      "connection": "degustfunction9451_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```

The error begins after create a out bidding (table)

My code snippet:

```
module.exports = function (context, myTimer,outputTable) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();

....
}
```

Bidings:

[image: Bidings]

Comment: Hi Paulo, may I know if the answer below helps your issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were breaking changes in 2.0.12050. You can refer to this page: https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129

The Azure Storage bindings (blob, queues and tables triggers and bindings) were previously part of the runtime, but moving forward, will need to be explicitly installed.

To temporarily avoid impact, you can pin your Function App to the previous version of the runtime by updating the app setting FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION to 2.0.11961-alpha

You can modify the FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION in visual studio code in your function's "Application Settings" or modify it on Azure portal by clicking "Configuration"(then under "Application settings"). Change it from "~2" to "~2.0.11961-alpha".